# Xcode: Setup imageView to be full screen in iPhone X

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x, xcode9.4

I'm trying to set imageView full screen in iPhone X but for some reasons it doesn't work.

Here an example:

[image]
As you can see the image below the image view is not completely full screen.

Any of you knows how can make full screen?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the safeAreaLayoutGuide , make the constraint with superView directly

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You can also cancel the safe area**

[image]